# Styled component uses props interface from inherited component, not its own props interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Given these React components:

Typography.tsx:

```
type TypographyProps = HTMLAttributes<HTMLHeadingElement> &
  PropsWithChildren & {
    id?: string
  }

const StyledTypography = styled.div`
  font-style: normal;
` 

export const Typography = (props: TypographyProps): ReactElement => (
  <StyledTypography {...props} />
)
```

Text.tsx:

```
import { Typography } from '../Typography'

type TextProps = TypographyProps & { bold?: boolean }

const Text = styled(Typography)<TextProps>`
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-style: ${({ bold }) => (bold ? 'bold' : 'normal')};
`
```

When consuming the component `<Text />` it uses the props interface `TypographyProps` and not `TextProps`. How do I structure the types so `<Text />` uses the `TextProps` type for props?

When I use: `<Text bold>`, `bold` gets passed down correctly, but there is no type safety. I can also pass a string for example.